# How can I tell if I'm connecting to Azure Sql Database

Tags: ado.net, azure-sql-database

Microsoft provides the same ADO.NET connector to Sql Server and Sql Database. How can I tell if the DB I'm connecting to is Sql Database?

And yes I can probably guess from the connection string. But I'd prefer to know for sure.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1):

Select @@version will return **Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM)** - 12.0.2000.8 ... for Azure Sql DB.

Thanks,
Mihaela